# How do I align the label and input in a one line?

Tags: html

Above is my form:
[image]

I want the label category to be horizontally at par with Select Category drop down. Same for other form items.

Here's my CSS:

```
.labelContainer {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;

}

.inputContainer {
  clear:left;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

And some of my HTML:

```
<div class="labelContainer">
            <label for="Date">Date</label>
        </div>

        <div class="inputContainer">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the clear:left from the .inputContainer class CSS :

CSS:

```
.labelContainer {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.inputContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **clear: left** on you **.inputContainer** prevents the two divs to be next to each other.

HTML:

```
<div class="labelContainer">
    <label for="Date">Date</label>
</div>
<div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
</div>
<div class='clearfix'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.labelContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.inputContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

You can check it here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3t3syak9/).

Answer (score 0):

Use  positioning to position your select menu

```
.inputContainer{
        position:relative;
        bottom:10px;
        left:20px;
}
```